# how can I close position on OKX V5 based on CCXT Python?

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, ccxt

I use this fuction : exchange.create_order(t[0][1], 'market', 'sell', 1, params={'reduceOnly': True})  can close positon on FTX, but I don't find the right way to deal on OKX exchange.
Could you please let me know how to close postion on OKX?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a code block and/or error message in the body of question. [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Also what type of product are you trading? Futures? Margin? Spot? Please edit question to include as much code as possible in a code block.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I used this function :exchange.create_order(‘XRP-USDT’, "limit", "long", 1, 0.41,
                                         {"tdMode": "cross", "side": "sell", "ccy": "USDT"})  created a Perpetrual contract on OKX, but I don't know how close this position.

Answer (score 4):

OKX requires some specific parameters in order to open or close a position. Please check out this simple example:

Opening a long position:

```
symbol = "LTC/USDT:USDT" 
side = 'buy'
type = 'market'
amount = 1
price = None

exchange_params = {
  'tdMode': 'cross' # margin: is required to be either "isolated" or "cross",
  'posSide': 'long' # direction either long or short
}

open_position = exchange.create_order(symbol, type, side, amount, price, exchange_params)
```

After executing the snippet above a position in that market will be opened, if we want to close it we just need to issue an order in the opposite direction, something like this:

```
side = 'sell' # opposite side
exchange_params = {
  'tdMode': 'cross' # margin: is required to be either "isolated" or "cross",
  'posSide': 'long' # opposite direction now
}

# symbol, amount, type remain the same in this case

close_position = exchange.create_order(symbol, type, side, amount, price, exchange_params)
```

Let me know if you need any other clarification!

Comment: You can also do away with the `posSide` parameter by changing from `long/short mode` to `net mode`. In `net mode`, users can only have positions in one direction; In `long/short mode`, users can hold positions in long and short directions. [Set position mode](https://www.okx.com/docs-v5/en/#rest-api-account-get-account-configuration)

Comment: Carlos, can you give me a hand (consegue me ajudar)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74690975/how-to-close-a-margin-order-in-okx-using-ccxt

Comment: I'm having more or less the same issue, I can't find the way to close a margin market order.