# How to close a margin order in OKX using CCXT

Tags: python, ccxt

I found an old thread ( [how can I close position on OKX V5 based on CCXT Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72374644/how-can-i-close-position-on-okx-v5-based-on-ccxt-python) ) but is not working.
I'm having problem in closing my current margin-spot position. Here's my code:

```
params = {'tdMode': 'cross', 'ccy': 'USDT'}
order = await self.okx.create_order(
    symbol='XRP/USDT', type='market', side='sell',
    amount=99.43, price=0.39024, params=params
)
```

Result:

```
{'amount': 99.431119,
 'average': 0.39005,
 'clientOrderId': 'e847386590ce4dBCce71dedc37e12254',
 'cost': 38.78310796595,
 'datetime': '2022-12-02T17:29:58.048Z',
 'fee': {'cost': 0.03878310796595, 'currency': 'USDT'},
 'fees': [{'cost': 0.03878310796595, 'currency': 'USDT'}],
 'filled': 99.431119,
 'id': '518962064594153472',
```

Places the first order correctly. Now to close this order I use barrely the same code, changing sides:

```
params = {'tdMode': 'cross', 'ccy': 'USDT'}
order = await self.okx.create_order(
    symbol='XRP/USDT', type='market', side='buy',
    amount=99.43, price=0.39017, params=params
)
```

Problem is that the amount in the second order seeems to be 'contracts'/'price' instead:

result:

```
{'amount': 99.43111,
 'average': 0.39015,
 'clientOrderId': 'e847386590ce4dBC328bc6dfc937795f',
 'cost': 99.43110980145,
 'datetime': '2022-12-02T17:36:47.913Z',
 'fee': {'cost': 0.254853543, 'currency': 'XRP'},
 'fees': [{'cost': 0.254853543, 'currency': 'XRP'}],
 'filled': 254.853543,
 'id': '518963783692562432',
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing the default `tgtCcy` value?

Can you try to place the market order without the price (market orders execute at the market price so you don't need to specify it)?

Comment: tgtCcy does not work, only for SPOT markets. I'll use the standard lib for closing all orders with market orders. Thank you Carlos!

Comment: @PieroCosta, if you can make it using the standard lib you can definitely do it using ccxt, you just need to realize the difference between the std lib and ccxt request :)